# Changing variables in file 1 using file 2

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, pygame

So I have 2 Python files, one is a PyGame game (just a movement game) and the other is a Tkinter form.
The game has a variable called `MOVESPEED` and I would like the Tkinter form to change it whenever needed.

The form currently has an entry box (where you will put the value of `"MOVESPEED"`) and a button which will submit that value, once that button is pushed, I would like it so somehow change `MOVESPEED` in the `pygame` file. (This change does not need to be permanent)

Thank you for any help, I'll give you more info if need be.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524031/python-tkinter-connect-variable-to-entry-widget

Comment: So, what is the problem? Have you tried `import pygame_module` and `pygame_module.MOVESPEED = stuff`? Or do you want to change it _in the code_? If so, why?

Comment: @tobias_k will that change it for the file that has MOVESPEED in it? or for the file that is importing it?

Comment: @tobias_k I tried to do this with 2 other files, one file set's x, then prints it every 1 second, i then made another file which imported it and set it to another number, but it just runs it as if it were the file i was trying to change.

Comment: Did you run those two files in the same python instance? In this case, it should work, but if you are changing that number from _another_ python instance, then you should consider storing those numbers is an external text file.

Comment: Separate instances, I really didn't want to use external files >.<