# cross platform gui..which tool to use?

Tags: python, user-interface, cross-platform

I am developing a python program (my native platform is Ubuntu) for which I would like to build a simple gui. I would like the GUI to be cross platform.I came across python-gtk/wxpython/qt.  What is the best tool to use?

Thanks

suresh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Python GUI framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394039/which-python-gui-framework)

Comment: Why not just look at it's API and use the one you like the most?

Comment: that is a really subjetive question, maybe you could add something about what is important to you

Comment: I saw similar questions being asked couple of years back..I thought, I would get the current opinion of the experts....

Comment: @suresh: I think most true experts will agree there is no definitive "best".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-platform gui toolkit for deploying Python applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520015/cross-platform-gui-toolkit-for-deploying-python-applications)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest tkinter. It's part of python, ridiculously easy to use, and of course is very cross platform.

Many people dismiss tkinter based on years-old knowledge, but tkinter has evolved a lot. Some say it looks ugly, but more often than not functionality and ease of use is more important. Tkinter is definitely the best *pragmatic* choice in my opinion.

That being said, however, there is no "best". Qt, Wx and Tk are all fine, all do pretty much the same, and are all more-or-less equally cross-platform. Pick any one of them and don't look back. Once you get experience with one of tnem you'll be in a position to decide for yourself which one is "best"

Comment: The screenshots I've seen of tkinter on OSX look pretty rough though. Is there an example that looks better than this? http://www.codebykevin.com/pylocate-aqua.png

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be either wxPython or Qt, although I'd lean strongly towards wxPython based on my previous use. Both of these have fairly good fidelity on both Windows and OSX and feel and look like native applications.

GTK has marginal Windows support and pretty bad support on OSX. I would recommend against it.

Comment: Tkinter is a perfectly fine choice, too.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt already suggested, wxPython should be the most portable choice. On Windows it uses the native GUI toolkit, on Linux it will use Qt as backend (I dunno what it does on OSX though, but you can probably find out all of that on their website).

Comment: Define "most portable". In my experience tkinter is more portable than wxpython. I almost am never able to spend a couple weeks with wxpython on one platform and then swith to amother without a fe tweaks. The opposite is true for me with tki te -- i rarely hve to make any tweaks for differnt platforms other than the obvious (filename convntions, etc)

Comment: Ok let me correct: wxPython is probably what you want to go for, as its fairly portable. I must confess I don't know too much about tkinter though except that I don't like its look on linux very much.