# Should I Use Tkinter, C or C# to Make a GUI in Python?

Tags: c#, python, c, user-interface, tkinter

I am building a quiz program which can be personalized but I want to add a GUI to it. I have seen some pieces of software which implement C and C# into Python. Should I use Tkinter to make the GUI or should I use C or C#. Can you also please tell me a good book for beginners which I can use to learn Tkinter/C/C#.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are considering C#, why not build the whole thing in C#?

Comment: @Programmer777 involving more than one language is a great way to make a simple project a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing a program, you should avoid using multiple languages unless you really need to, especially for a simple GUI program.

In this case, learning C/C# specifically for the purpose of creating a GUI seems like overkill to me -- not only would you need to learn an entirely new programming language, but you would need to learn how to use whatever GUI library is popular from within C/C#! You'd be right back where you started -- having to learn how to use some library.

Instead, Python has several great GUI libraries that you can use. Tkinter is bundled by default within the Python standard, but there *are* other GUI libraries that are available, like wxPython or PyQt. Here's [a comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520055/646543) of different Python GUI libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use .NET GUI components you'll have to switch to IronPython. You cannot use the standard CPython implementation and build a .NET GUI.

With the standard CPython you can use Tkinter, but I would suggest to take a look at PySide (or PyQt4). It's much nicer to work with, and it looks better.

[PyQt4 Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial Viktor!

Comment: You can embed standard python into your .NET code, its not trivial, but its pretty standard C integration. That being said, I don't recommend it for simple projects. https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html