# Python GUI programming, Licensing and Understanding

Tags: python, pyqt, pygtk, gui-toolkit

I have been working on python recently and I have been making quite alot of research on the best x-platform UI toolkit. I dont really want something heavy because i am a lone developing switching from c# and there is possibility I will be selling some of my application in my locality.

I tried `PyQt` and I am beginning to love it, although, it appears that `PyGTK` is a bit mature.

Like I said earlier, I am not keen about heavy native look and feel but please not like Tk, I was stuck at the licensing issue of `PyQt` as you might not be able to sell programs written in it. someone introduced Pyside but from what I am seeing, it is not stable and well maintained.

- My question is, can i sell my `PyQt` written application
- is `pyGTK` any better than `PyQt`, give reasons
- Is there any other x-platform easy to learn and implement and license problem free UI toolkit for python out there that i can use

Educative reply will be much appreciated

Comment: Here's a list of other UI implementations and their merits: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520015/cross-platform-gui-toolkit-for-deploying-python-applications

Comment: Thanks but I think I will just stick with PyQt's Junior brother PySide, At least i am free from commercial licensing in that regards, thanks again

Comment: Np, this was in reply to your third part (if there were any other platforms easy to learn and implement).  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

From the [PyQt website](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/commercial/pyqt):

> Like Qt itself, Riverbank's software (PyQt5, PyQt4, PyQtChart, PyQtMobility, dip and QScintilla2) is provided under a number of licenses depending on how it is going to be used.
>
> The free versions are licensed under the GNU General Public License. If your use of Riverbank's software is compatible with the GPL then you do not need to buy a commercial license.
>
> If your use of Riverbank's software is not compatible with the GPL then you require a commercial license.

My basic understanding of the GPL terms are that commercial releases are ok but any software that "uses" the GPL licensed software must also be released as open source under a GPL compatible license.  What exactly "uses" means would probably require a lawyer :)

---

I've never had much luck getting PyGTK to work however I've had no real issues with simple GUIs and the LPGL licensed `PySide`.  The documentation is so-so and I've had to refer to the Qt C++ documentation a bit, but on the whole its been very stable and integrates well with MatplotLib for plotting.

E.g. these simple GUIs with live plots I have made using PySide.  The first only took about ten minutes to code by hand, however for more complicated GUIs you can also use QtDesigner.

[image: Gui using PySide]

[image: GUI 2 using PySide]

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the foul word, `GTk sucks`, I will stick to Pyside but please, is PySide and PyQt using the same coding and libraries, where do you think I can get a good documentation for PySide and lastly, Pyside seems to be bundled with the Qt heavy 600Mb library, where do you think i can download only pyside bundle like the way I installed PyQt. Thanks and note: I use windows 7

Comment: Got the PySide window binary download page http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/pyside/PySide-1.2.1.win32-py3.3.exe remaining PDF documentation. Thanks will post any reasonable thing I find

Comment: Try this for starters http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/, beyond that, SO and google. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks really appreciate, I think I'm done googling this issue. Thanks again

Comment: No problems.  By the way on SO if an answer correctly addresses your question then you should mark it so using the little green tick... from looking at your profile you haven't selected any answers as correct yet!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any other x-platform easy to learn and implement and license problem free UI toolkit for python out there that i can use

[Try Kivy](http://kivy.org/). MIT license, quite nice API and documentation, works on Android and iOS.

There is a chance you'll fall in love with this framework. You have been warned.

Comment: Seen it, it is targeted at mobile devices, I want toolkit for web, pyside is far easy to learn with qt designer

Comment: What do you mean by "toolkit for web"? Anyway, I would not say mobile devices, but touch devices. But you are not limited by it, really, you can react on right click of your mouse button (you just need to set some variable). The showcase is just to show people that they can use it on touch devices, unlike, well, most of the other frameworks and libraries.

Comment: I've come across Kivy before and also been turned off a bit by the "touch" focus.  It does look quite interesting though e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7UKmK9eQLY

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I want a toolkit for desktop application not `web`, I really liked the [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home) and [pymt](http://pymt.eu/) they are almost the same, but they dont meet my need.